# Extending Groovy String class

Tags: groovy, template-engine, frontend, extend

Groovy allows to do some nice things with strings in frontend pages, like:

`${"hello".capitalize()}`

How can I add a new custom method to the `String` class? Like:

`${"hello".custom()}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the metaClass

```
String.metaClass.custom = { //dosomething }
```

See http://www.groovyexamples.org/2010/07/19/dynamically-add-properties-to-a-class/